# Sending push notifications when a user likes your post like Instagram

Tags: swift, firebase, instagram

I'm practicing Swift programming by trying to build Instagram for fun. I am using firebase as my database. I was able to set up the activity page where it shows a user has liked/commented on your post.

Now I am wondering how can I actually send a push notification when that happens? I tried using FirebaseMessaging but all I can really do is send messages from firebase directly.

How do I send a specific user a push notification that someone has liked their post?

Comment: you can with firebase functions see this example https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Firebase functions. Here are the basic concepts:

1. To receive notifications, user must subscribe to a "topic" using subscribeToTopic(String topic)
2. Whenever a post from that topic is created, you use firebase messaging to send message to that topic
3. To do that, you need to host a function to firebase. That function listens to new posts being posted at whatever node you are using
4. Everytime a new post is written to that node, it sends the message

Here is the link to the of an example [Firebase Functions Example](https://github.com/selingSJSU/Zero/tree/master/functions) (the function to be hosted is sendNotificationToLocation).

Check this on how to handle subscribing/unsubscribing and handling message/notification [Firebase messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: But maybe one question regarding that. How do you send the push notification only to the user whose post has been liked?

Answer (score 0):

1. First do the all configurations for Firebase Cloud Messaging.
2. Then get firebase registration token of the user whom you want to send a push notifications to.
3. [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564301/7233049) for detailed explanation