# Firebase, Swift: Send a push notification to specific user given device token

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have a Firebase Swift chat app where I'd like to send a push notification to a specific user. I have already captured and have access to the user's device token.

All the references mention having to have a 'web app' to manage this, but I haven't managed to find any specific examples of this.

1. Is it necessary to have a web app to manage push notifications for Firebase?
2. If so, are there any examples of how this can work?

Thank you.

Comment: You can either use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) or your own server. Example using Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: I have already answered this in another question, feel free to check if out in case you need some help on this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481992/firebase-chat-push-notifications/37684936#37684936

Comment: @ZassX thank you for taking the time to answer but your linked answer is wrong - I now have this working with Cloud Functions (thanks @nathan)

Comment: @XCodeWarrier No problem. I didn't say it was the right answer, it is an alternative you can consider using. Just as an idea. Glad you solved it!
PS: You should update your answer and paste your solution here so it can help other with same problem. :)

Answer (score 8):

- First do the all **configuration** for **Firebase Cloud Messaging**. Can follow this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client
- Now you need to access **Firebase registration token** for your associated user whom you want to send a push notification. You can get this token by following below steps:

  1. Add **'Firebase/Messaging'** pod to your project.
  2. **`import FirebaseMessaging`** in your **`AppDelegate.swift`** file.
  3. Conform **MessagingDelegate** protocol to your **`AppDelegate`** class.
  4. Write **`didRefreshRegistrationToken`** delegate method and get your user's registration token:
- Now you are ready to send push notification to your specific user. Send notification as below:

  ```
  func sendPushNotification(payloadDict: [String: Any]) {
     let url = URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!
     var request = URLRequest(url: url)
     request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
     // get your **server key** from your Firebase project console under **Cloud Messaging** tab
     request.setValue("key=enter your server key", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
     request.httpMethod = "POST"
     request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: payloadDict, options: [])
     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
          print(error ?? "")
          return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
          print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
          print(response ?? "")
        }
        print("Notfication sent successfully.")
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print(responseString ?? "")
     }
     task.resume()
  }
  ```
- Now call above function as:

  ```
  let userToken = "your specific user's firebase registration token"
  let notifPayload: [String: Any] = ["to": userToken,"notification": ["title":"You got a new meassage.","body":"This message is sent for you","badge":1,"sound":"default"]]
  self.sendPushNotification(payloadDict: notifPayload)
  ```

Comment: This works very well for sending notifications without making a web app. Very helpful!

Comment: This still works? When I do the func nothing happens. Edit. The console says: Notfication sent successfully.
{"multicast_id":269539832962150,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"1657369222891"}]}. But no push on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it is not necessary to have a web app to manage push notifications with Firebase**

Look at the answer from Ashvini, it gives you a method to send messages directly from your iOS app, to other devices.

You can also use the Firebase Console to manually send push messages to multiple users at the same time.

Here is the documentation for sending messages through a web app/server. [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)